# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime Error when try to sow date and time data into DateTimePicker from DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datetimepicker, sqlyog

I want to display Date and time **(format: dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt)** from column "DateTime to DateTimePicker. but it shows an error **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

```
Private Sub dgvSchedule_RowEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvSchedule.RowEnter
        'DISPLAYS COLUMN VALUE IN TEXTBOXES
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow
            row = Me.dgvSchedule.Rows(e.RowIndex)
            txtID.Text = row.Cells("Patient_ID_Number").Value.ToString

            dtpDate.Text = row.Cells("Date_Time").Value 'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCUR

            txtFirstname.Text = row.Cells("Firstname").Value.ToString
            txtLastname.Text = row.Cells("Lastname").Value.ToString
            txtPhoneNumber.Text = row.Cells("Phone_Number").Value.ToString
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: THe DateTime picker needs a Date And Time for the value always..  You cant skip the date part.  Create a DateTime variable using today's date, if the control is set to just show the time, just that part will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the format of your 'Date_Time' column?

If it's a MySQL datetime like this: `2016-01-23 23:30:55` then you can just use the `DateTime.Parse` of VB.NET

```
Dim new_date As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-23 23:30:55")
DateTimePicker1.Value = new_date
```

Note that the format is 'Custom' and the CustomFormat is `dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt`

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt"
```

So the final code could be:

```
 DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
 DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt"

 Dim new_date As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells("Date_Time").Value.ToString())
 DateTimePicker1.Value = new_date
```

I also noticed that you are using:

```
dtpDate.Text = row.Cells("Date_Time").Value
```

instead of

```
dtpDate.Value = row.Cells("Date_Time").Value
```

Note that these are different: **Text** and **Value**.

Comment: sir. The error still occur at the line  **Dim new_date As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells("Date_Time").Value.ToString())**. I'm using SQLYog and the datatype of the column Date_Time is varchar. is that ok?

Comment: Hi there. Could you give an example of a Date_Time value? I think the problem is with your string format.

Comment: My DateTimePicker format is customized **MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt** so when the value was saved on the database, it will be like this **01/24/2016 12:00 PM**.


my **Date_Time column datatype is varchar with length 100**

Comment: Hi there. Yes, it should actually work. I also noticed that you are using `dtpDate.Text = row.Cells("Date_Time").Value`, instead of Text, you need it to be Value.

So that's `dtpDate.Value = DateTime.Parse(row.Cells("Date_Time").Value.ToString())`

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH IT WORKED!

Comment: That's good to hear. If you may, please click on the 'check' to 'accept' the answer.